# Assembled new PC but cannot get to OS installer main menu - suspected GPU?

Tags: installation, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I have assembled a new PC, all the parts are brand new except for the PSU and GPU.

I have encountered various problems in trying to install all of (all from USB):

- manjaro-xfce-20.2-minimal-201203-linux59.iso
- pop-os_20.10_amd64_intel_3.iso
- ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso
- Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso
- ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
- linuxmint-20-cinnamon-64bit.iso
- lubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso

I can never get to the real start of the OS installer - only to the first grub menu which says (depends slightly on OS)

```
Install <OS>
Try <OS>
```

I have seen errors of the following

- Black screen and restart
- Motherboard splash 'Pro Series' then black screen
- Install spinner for a second then black screen
- Install spinner immediate freeze
- [drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting. (Then black)
- [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!

I have tried adding various combinations of arguments in the grub command from the following list

- nomodeset
- xforcevesa
- amdgpu.dc=0
- amdgpu.dc=1
- radeon.modeset=0
- amdgpu.runpm=0
- amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9
- radeon.cik_support=0
- amdgpu.cik_support=1
- radeon.si_support=0
- amdgpu.si_support=1
- radeon.cik_support=1
- amdgpu.cik_support=0
- radeon.si_support=1
- amdgpu.si_support=0
- modprobe.blacklist=radeon
- modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu

The pattern of debug led's on the MOBO is:

- On initial power on: CPU/RAM/VGA/BOOT turn on for 1-2 seconds each in that order then stay off.
- Just before black screen: CPU turns on for about 1 second, then everything off.

Finally my hardware is:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT 3.8 GHz 6-Core Processor
- MOBO: MSI B450M PRO-VDH MAX Micro ATX AM4
- RAM: ADATA XPG GAMMIX D10 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3600 CL18 Memory (I have 2 plugged in in slots 2 and 4 numbered by distance from CPU)
- DISK: ADATA XPG SX8200 Pro 1 TB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive
- GPU: Radeon R9 290
- PSU: Corsair CX 750 W 80+ Bronze Certified ATX Power Supply

I'm really lost. I'm tempted to buy a new GPU and hope that works

Note: My end goal is to get Ubuntu/Lubuntu working, I tried the others just to see if they worked.

Thank you so much

UPDATE:

I just tried using the same PSU and GPU with a very old mobo, cpu, ram combo and then by launching with a lubuntu USB I was successfully able to boot.
Since this setup is much lower power it makes me wonder if the PSU cannot support the new components. The strange thing is that it's an estimated 444 watts in total, which is much less than the 750 advertised by the PSU.

UPDATE:
The PC is now booting and I have successfully installed lubuntu. It is working with only 1 stick of RAM in slot 2. Although I had tried this before, this time I'm using the other stick. My best conclusion is that 1 stick is faulty.

Comment: You did supply power to the GPU and the two connectors on the MB?  Did you try with each of the memory modules separately?

Comment: Yes there is power to the gpu, cpu (on mobo) and into the ATX power (mobo). Do the symptoms I describe sound like a power problem? I didn't think of that

Comment: I didn't actually try each ram slot separately, but I did try only slot 2. The mobo manual says slot 2 is the one you should use.

Comment: Since you did see the grub menu, every component you mentioned is working - until they really start getting used.  The 750Watt PSU should be able to handle it, but it isn't new.  Can you borrow another one just to try?  I would try other memory slots - never had such a problem, but it's worth trying.  Also: you didn't mention anything about CPU cooling.

Comment: The CPU is cooled with a Wraith Cooler (sink + fan) that came with it. It's pretty tight on, there is also paste (also came pre-painted). The bios menu shows CPU 25 celsius. I don't have another PSU to borrow, but it would be strange for the PSU to fail no? I should say the PSU and GPU have been fixed in another case untouched for about 18 months. Will try other RAM slots.

Comment: Personal experience: PSU are number two in the toppop of failures, bested only by hard disks - spinning or ssd.  I don't want to frighten you, but I had a NEW MB that failed, recently.  Pre-painted paste on CPU: did you have to remove a sticker?

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose it could be the PSU. My mobo+cpu setup was exactly like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DdP1DLGrwg. The paste came on the bottom of the heat sink, and it was a very even layer.